# How to rename a folder in WebAPI :C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-web-api

I am new to WebAPI ,I am trying to rename a folder within WebAPI itself.

for that I am using  `Directory.Move('source', 'destination');`

source : `D:\\Projects\\Dot Net\\ChurchAdmin\\ChurchAdmin\\api\\Images\\Announcements\\Church\\ComitteeMeetings`

destination : D`:\\Projects\\Dot Net\\ChurchAdmin\\ChurchAdmin\\api\\Images\\Announcements\\Church\\Meeting`

When I debug this line `Directory.Move('source', 'destination');` I got the error as follows `ExceptionMessage: "Could not find a part of the path."`

I tried in many ways I can't resolve this issue .Can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: You are using *relative* paths. Most likely the current director isn't the one you think. I suspect you are in `bin\debug`. Use `Path.GetFullPath` to find out what the current path is.

Answer (score 0):

[GetFullPath(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Returns the absolute path for the specified path string.
Check my tested Example on console application:-

Simple use **Path.GetFullPath(yourRelativePath);** thats it

**@Panagiotis you are right**

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string source_dir = "C:\\Users\\hitesh.anshani\\Documents\\visual studio 2017\\Projects\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\hitesh";
            string des_dir = "C:\\Users\\hitesh.anshani\\Documents\\visual studio 2017\\Projects\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\hitesh1233";
            var abc = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            Directory.Move(Path.GetFullPath(source_dir), Path.GetFullPath(des_dir));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      string sourceDirectory = @"D:\Projects\Dot Net\ChurchAdmin\ChurchAdmin\api\Images\Announcements\Church\ComitteeMeetings"
      string destinationDirectory = @"D:\Projects\Dot Net\ChurchAdmin\ChurchAdmin\api\Images\Announcements\Church\Meetings"
      try
      {
         System.IO.Directory.Move(sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory);
      } 
      catch (Exception eX)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(eX.Message);
      }
   }
}
```